# Can’t “request desktop” in mobile Safari

Tags: bug, mobile-web, mobile-safari

Whenever I tap on “[request desktop site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFdjJ.jpg)” in mobile Safari it just reloads the current page but doesn’t switch to the full site.

(I don’t use any other mobile browsers so I don’t know if any others are affected.)

It used to work before and I would use it pretty often because I just can’t seem to stay on the full site for whatever reason. It’s a lot more effort to have to scroll to the bottom and tap on the tiny “full site” link.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed, although I’m not sure how. In any case, I am using the new request desktop *switch* (under website settings), which prevents it from reverting back at any point, even in incognito and also the browser in the SE app. (The only problem is that it needs to be done on each site and its meta, so I’m going to be doing this a lot, even if it was less often than before.)

[image: screenshot of setting off]

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't fixed yet, just pointing out yet if you want the full site all the time on mobile, your settings are saved for that device. So whenever I visit the SE site on mobile it will save my previous settings.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to save my settings though. Even though it’s the same browser, some combination of switching SE sites and toggling incognito mode always seems to put me back at the mobile site.