# Is it possible to make the "full site" persistent for mobile across Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, mobile-web, full-site

The "full site" setting seems to be stored in a cookie that has a frequent expiry time, and it's unique for every SE site.

Whenever it expires, it is a pain to have to click on the tiny link on the bottom for each SE site you visit (I visit a lot of them) only to have to do the same after a few weeks.

Would it be possible to have a setting in the network profile to force "full site" for all SE sites?

Comment: Yes, please! Seeing that phasing out the mobile site isn't going to happen the next 6-8 cookie expiries thus would be a neat solution ad interim.

Comment: If you're on iOS, you can [make Safari request the desktop site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336883/323179) for you, but you must apply this setting to every site and meta site separately (I visit a lot of sites too but it's not as bad as it sounds). I've never had it switch back.

Comment: @Laurel: That's a good idea, unfortunately on firefox when you select "request desktop site" the result is extremely zoomed out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrQeQ.png. With "full site" it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItPhJ.png

Comment: Just FYI, this was posted by the front-end designer recently and might be of interest to you: [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views). The full-site view will soon be the default (at least by the end of the year).

Comment: @CaveJohnson: that's great news!